# There is no scrolling and no onclick , for a scroll view inside a custom adapter for a list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

**What i have :**

i have a listView in which , i am using custom adapter . custom adapter is a resource for views inside listView (https://www.dropbox.com/s/lty9abmss7uq2aw/Untitled_1.png)

**what i want to do :** 
i want , whenever i click in that view (https://www.dropbox.com/s/8umltk95vf2gze9/Untitled.png)  click is not working properly in the whole view (https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz4h2nrwjz36ryf/Untitled_2.png)

**Why this is not working :** 
i know why this is not working , because i am using ScrollView inside that Layout . scrollview in included in Layout .

Layout is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/odxw8ihkcyowngu/activity_custom_list_view.xml

ScrollView is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdm1ftbgbje20k4/dialogbox.xml

**How to make a Scrollable_View inside a listView which is clickable in whole area .**

Comment: you can't scroll listview inside scrollview so,you need extended listview height dynamically on your code!

Comment: i have scrollview inside a list view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to add an onclick() to the TextView that is inside the scrollView